# SQL DB2 query error

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to get a hang on SQL, but I dont know why this doesn't work.

```
    SELECT p.Ort, COUNT(Projekt.Ort) AS Anzahl
    FROM Projekt p
    WHERE Anzahl > 2 GROUP BY p.Ort;
```

If I try to use this I get:

```
    "ANZAHL" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Comment: Thanks solved by valex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should HAVING instead of WHERE

```
  SELECT p.Projektort, COUNT(Projekt.Projektort) AS ProjektAnzahl
  FROM Projekt p
  GROUP BY p.Projektort
  HAVING COUNT(Projekt.Projektort) > 2 ;
```

Comment: WHERE is used to choose which individual rows to use from the table(s) before processong them.  HAVING is evaluated after grouping.

Answer (score 1):

In GROUP BY clauses, the HAVING keyword is used:

```
SELECT p.Projektort, COUNT(Projekt.Projektort) AS ProjektAnzahl
FROM Projekt p
GROUP BY p.Projekt
HAVING ProjektAnzahl > 2
```